# Read values of multiple homogeneous Xlm Files and write into csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I have multiple xml-files which look like this:

```
<Bundle xmlns="xxx">
   <entry>
      <resource>
         <Composition xmlns="xxx">
            <title value="Comptitle"></title>
         </Composition>
      </resource>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <resource>
         <Person xmlns="xxx">
            <name>
               <family value="Doe"></family>
               <given value="John"></given>
            </name>
            <telecom>
               <system value="phone"></system>
               <value value="12345"></value>
            </telecom>
            <gender value="male"></gender>
            <birthDate value="1999-09-09"></birthDate>
            <address>
               <line value="Somestreet 66"></line>
               <city value="Cityname"></city>
               <postalCode value="11111"></postalCode>
               <country value="000012"></country>
            </address>
         </Person>
      </resource>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <fullUrl value="xxx"></fullUrl>
      <resource>
         <Organization xmlns="xxx">
            <name value="Name I need"></name>
         </Organization>
      </resource>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <fullUrl value="xxx"></fullUrl>
      <resource>
         <Organization xmlns="xxx">
            <name value="Name i don't need"></name>
         </Organization>
      </resource>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <fullUrl value="xxx"></fullUrl>
      <resource>
         <Information xmlns="xxx">
            <valueString value="This is important"></valueString>
            <interpretation>
               <coding>
                  <code value="i need this"></code>
               </coding>
            </interpretation>
            <note>
               <text value="Also this"></text>
            </note>
            <note>
               <text value="connected in one cell with this"></text>
            </note>
         </Information>
      </resource>
   </entry>
</Bundle>
```

The output should be a table (csv preferred) with all these in seperate rows. So basically:

```
filename1;Comptitle;familyname;givenname;phone etc.
filename2;Comptitle;familyname;givenname;phone etc.
filename3;Comptitle;familyname;givenname;phone etc.
.
.
.
```

I have a clear idea of how to loop through the desired code with a list of the filenames and how to add the information of each file to a table.
My code looks like this:

```
$information= Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml -Path $testpath -File
$information| Out-File $filelistold #I'm going to need this one later

$result = $information| 
    ForEach-Object {
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding utf8
        foreach ($item in $xml.Bundle.entry.resource) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "File"=$_.Name
                "Comptitle"= $item.Composition.title.value 
                "Family Name"= $item.Person.name.family.value
                "First Name"= $item.Person.name.given.value
                "Street"= $item.Person.address.line.value
                "Postal Code"= $item.Person.address.postalCode.value
                "City" = $item.Person.address.city.value
                "Organization"= $item.Organization.name.value -join ""
                "Information"= $item.Information.valuestring.value -join ""
                "Comment"= $item.Information.note.text.value -join ""
            }
        }
    }


$result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | set-content -Path $testcsv
```

The output looks like this now:

```
"filename";;"Doe";"John";"Somestreet 66";"11111";"Cityname";"";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"Name I need";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"Name I don't need";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"";"";""
"filename";;;;;;;"";"Information";"Comment"
"filename";;;;;;;"";"";""
```

How do i avoid the empty lines and put all information in one line?

Edit: I solved the problem by using `SelectNodes` instead of writing out the whole XPath. I stumbled upon several problems while trying that. I first had to designate the namespace defined in the root node like this:

```
$ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
        $ns.AddNamespace("ns", "xxx")
```

then navigate to the values i need like this:

```
"Comptitle"= $xml.SelectNodes("//ns:title",$ns)[0]|select -ExpandProperty value
```

Now everything is written into a csv without needing to delete empty spaces.

Comment: Filter the rows with all empty or whitespace fields (excluding the 'File' field) with: `$result | Where-Object { (($_.PsObject.Properties.Value | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'File'}) -join '') -match '\S' } | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. The output is exactly the same.